# Error al programar en android studio

Tags: java, android, array

No se por que me dice que el `Método Lugar()` no se puede aplicar en la clase `Lugar` para sus parámetros que le pasamos.

```
package com.example.mislugares;

public class Lugar {
public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getDireccion() {
    return direccion;
}

public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
    this.direccion = direccion;
}

public GeoPunto getPosicion() {
    return posicion;
}

public void setPosicion(GeoPunto posicion) {
    this.posicion = posicion;
}

public String getFoto() {
    return foto;
}

public void setFoto(String foto) {
    this.foto = foto;
}

public int getTelefono() {
    return telefono;
}

public void setTelefono(int telefono) {
    this.telefono = telefono;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public String getComentario() {
    return comentario;
}

public void setComentario(String comentario) {
    this.comentario = comentario;
}

public long getFecha() {
    return fecha;
}

public void setFecha(long fecha) {
    this.fecha = fecha;
}
public TipoLugar getTipo() {
    return tipo;
}

public void setTipo(TipoLugar tipo) {
    this.tipo = tipo;
}
private String nombre;
private String direccion;
private GeoPunto posicion;
private String foto;
private int telefono;
private String url;
private String comentario;
private TipoLugar tipo;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Lugar{" +
            "nombre='" + nombre + '\'' +
            ", direccion='" + direccion + '\'' +
            ", posicion=" + posicion +
            ", foto='" + foto + '\'' +
            ", telefono=" + telefono +
            ", url='" + url + '\'' +
            ", comentario='" + comentario + '\'' +
            ", tipo=" + tipo +
            ", fecha=" + fecha +
            '}';
}

private long fecha;



public Lugar(String nombre, String direccion, double longitud, double latitud, int telefono, String url, String comentario, int valoracion, TipoLugar tipo)
{
    fecha = System.currentTimeMillis();
    posicion = new GeoPunto(0, 0);
   tipo = TipoLugar.OTROS;


}
}
```

Y aquí donde da el error :

```
    public int nuevo() {                 
    Lugar lugar = new Lugar();       
    vectorLugares.add(lugar);        
    return vectorLugares.size()-1;   
}
```

Comment: Porque le pones -1 a `vectorLugares.size()`?

Answer (score 3):

veo que estas llamando al constructor sin paramentros, y por lo que hay en el código tu lo definiste con parámetros. Tendrías que definirle un constructor sin parámetros.

En la clase:

```
public class Lugar{
//....
    public Lugar(){}
//.....
}
```

a simple vista ahí está el error. Lo probé en NetBeans con java.

Comment: En java todas las clases tienen un constructor vacío por defecto, aunque no lo declaren.

Comment: Claro, pero si se declara un constructor en la clase, al parecer deja de tomar el constructor por defecto. Por lo tanto hay que integrarlo para que tome el constructor vacío de nuevo.

Comment: Si, en el momento que se declara un constructor, "desaparece" lo que había por defecto, va a tener que declarar el constructor sin parámetros